# VB: How to get all keys given Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Tags: json, vb.net, vba, linq, visual-studio-2015

I am using Newtonsoft.Json here (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) in Visual basic program in visual studio 2015.

```
Dim jObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString)
```

jsonString is:

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "0":{
      "name": "component 0",
      "primary": "R"
  },
  "1":{
      "name": "component 1",
      "primary": "C"
  }
}
```

How to get all keys of sub dictionaries from jObject (in this case: "0" and "1")?

By the way, is there good API documents for newtonsoft in VB? There are so many in C#, but few in VB. difficult to use them in my program. Thanks.

Comment: the problem is that "total" is in the same collection as "0" and "1"

Comment: @Plutonix, how to get "total", "0", "1"???   is there good API documents for newtonsoft in VB?

Comment: Use the answer posted (fix the typos) then `Dim keys = myObj.Keys` to get those keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the object you are trying to deserialize isn't strongly typed, I think your options are limited.

You could deserialize to Dictionary(of string, object).

```
Dim myObj as Dictionary(of string, object)
myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of Dictionary(of string, object))(json)
```

If you have any control over the json and can make those elements (not the "total" element) their own array, then you could create a class to deserialize into.

Would rather see the below if you had the ability to adjust that json (per comment from @BAE).

```
{
  "total": 2,
  "Items": [
  "0":{
      "name": "component 0",
      "primary": "R"
  },
  "1":{
      "name": "component 1",
      "primary": "C"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but are there good API documents for newtonsoft in VB? It is hard to use them before I found more useful docs

Comment: I didn't find any, but I don't mind using their c# docs and then just pasting into [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) if it needs to be vb-readable.